# Как создать несколько объектов через один конструктор? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
function Students(name, course, avgmark){
    this.name = name;
    this.course = course;
    this.avgmark = avgmark;
}

let students = new Students("Vasya", 3, 3.9)
```

Попробую объяснить, что мне нужно, на данном примере я создаю 1 объект, в который передаю 3 параметра, а как сделать так, чтобы я мог создать список, чтобы на выходе было

```
Vasya, 3, 3.9
Kolya, 2, 4.1
Masha, 4, 4.2 и тд.
```

Если я неправильно описал или неправильно написал код, вот само задание
"Определить новый объект с именем «Students», который можно создать с помощью «new», используя его конструктор. Конструктор принимает один параметр в виде строки - это список студентов и их курс и средний балл: «Вася», 3, 3,9; "Коля", 2, 4.1; «Маша», 4, 4.2; и тд. Объект «Students» должен иметь следующие методы:(с методами я попробую сам разобраться, просто они должны быть, а пока не могу правильно загуглить этот вопрос(( )

Comment: Массив объектов, не?

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον, Не, скорее велосипед по логике стандартного `Map`... возможно, с парой специфичных операций (помимо чтения и записи) в методах - типа фильтра по среднему баллу, например. Задачка явно на знание прототипной модели, а не массивов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function Student(str) {
   [this.name, this.course, this.average_mark] = str.split(",")
 }
 
 function Students(str) {
   this.list = [];
    
   str.split(";").forEach(row => {
     this.list.push(new Student(row));
   });
 }

 var students = new Students("Вася, 3, 3.9; Коля, 2, 4.1; Маша, 4, 4.2")
 console.log(students.list)
```

если правильно Вас понял, то что-то такое получается

Comment: Да, спасибо, вроде как то, что нужно, если не сложно, можете объяснить, что конкретно делает метод Students?

Comment: Разбивает общую строку, где записаны все студенты по символу ;
Таким образом получаем 3 подстроки(row), в каждой описан один студент.
Т.е. у forEach 3 итерации, соответственно создастся 3 объекта Student

Answer (score 4):

```js
function Student(name, course, avgmark){
    this.name = name;
    this.course = course;
    this.avgmark = avgmark;
}

let students = [
  new Student("Vasya", 3, 3.9),
  new Student("Kolya", 2, 4.1),
  new Student("Masha", 4, 4.2)
];
console.log(students);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function Students(data) {
  this._data = data.split(/\s*;\s*/).reduce((rslt, studentData) => {
    const [name, course, avgmark] = studentData.split(/\s*,\s*/); 
    return Object.assign(rslt, { [name]: { course, avgmark } }); 
  }, {}); 
}; 

Students.prototype.get = function (studentName) {
  return this._data[studentName]; 
}; 
Students.prototype.set = function (studentName, { course, avgmark }) {
  const studentData = this._data[studentName] || { course, avgmark }; 
  this._data[studentName] = {
    course : course  || studentData.course, 
    avgmark: avgmark || studentData.avgmark, 
  }; 
  return this; 
}; 

const students = new Students('Вася, 3, 3.9; Коля, 2, 4.1; Маша, 4, 4.2'); 
console.log('Коля:', students.get('Коля')); 
console.log('Коля переведен на третий курс:',
  students.set('Коля', { course: '3' }).get('Коля')
);
```